# Using rigidbody why is my gameObject falling all the time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

1.There is a error I am constantly getting. Not a programing error but a error in the sense that my game Object is constantly falling on the ground.

2.Every time I click on a and d(left and right) it moves horizontally.

The script I created with the help of my book L(earning c# by developing games with unity 2021 ) is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerBehavoiur : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float MoveSpeed = 10f;
  public float RotateSpeed = 75f;
  public int hp = 0;
  //stores a rigidbody
  private Rigidbody _rb;
  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
  }
  private float _hInput1;
  private float _vInput1;
  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
   /*MoveForward(_hInput1);
   RotateUpWards(_vInput1);
   */
   }
   /*public void MoveForward(float _vInput)
   {
   _vInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MoveSpeed;
   this.transform.Translate()
   }
  public void RotateUpWards(float _hInput)
  {
   _hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * RotateSpeed;
   this.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * _hInput * Time.deltaTime);
  }
    */
 void FixedUpdate()
 {
 SetVerticalDirection();
 SetHorizontalDirection();
 //makes the object move by horizontal input in the up direction
 Vector3 rotation = Vector3.up * _hInput1;
 /*this is the rotation of the game object 
 * moving up and then going at a fixed frame rate
 */
 Quaternion angleRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
 //this takes vertical input and addes the position and makes it move forward
 //the vertical input is the vertical axis whihc moves at a defined rate tht we can define
 _rb.MovePosition(this.transform.position + 
 this.transform.forward * _vInput1 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
 /*the move rotation moves using the rigibody rotation times the 
 * horizontal input times and moves up and rotates at the rotate speed rate
 */
 _rb.MoveRotation(_rb.rotation * angleRotation);
}
void SetVerticalDirection()
{
_vInput1 = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MoveSpeed;
}
    void SetHorizontalDirection()
    {
        _hInput1 = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * RotateSpeed;
    }
    /*Horizontal: ad
     * Vertical: ws
     */
}
```

This code controls the player motion using the input manager for taking vertical and horizontal issue

Comment: is the gravity scale of the rigidbody set to `0`?

Comment: Amazing how many people don't read the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html. "Even without adding any code, a Rigidbody object will be pulled downward by gravity"

Comment: I see what you're saying @Absinthe reading the docs is always a proof read and helps in developing. But well I needed help tailored to my specific problem thus I came here. Will read it once. I haven't checked the gravity scale. Infract I didn't know there was. Thanks for Informing